# search for string starting with ABC in a description field in redshift sql

Tags: sql, string, search, amazon-redshift, string-matching

I am trying to search for ABC in description :

Case 1: ABC 3463 XYZ check 1
output : ABC 3463

Case 2:***gdknkk_name_8ac47ab1418dfddddddd67a1de0c7f6f1b*** | ABC -4434
output : ABC -4434

case3 : ABC_Training
output : ABC_Training

case4:  ABCXXX FTP check 1
output : ABCXXX

Search for ABC with number in a string and show in output. tried using regexp_matches in SQL. what SQL function in redshift will work ?  Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
regexp_substr(description,
              'ABC([^ ]+|( [-0-9]+))'
             )
```

That is, either a string that starts with ABC and has additional characters.  Or ABC followed by a space and one or more digits.

Comment: Its working for few cases.  eg for ___hina_fac0419533a34ea08a1d48091b98cc62___ | ABC-4091 INS check complete  Output is: ABC-4091    but for   ___face_4fbb794b5a7a4e86aaaa809874162045___ | ABC-4466 name1: GO1                           Output is:  ABC-4091 name

Comment: I don't see how `'ABC-4091'` could be returned in the second case when that is not even in the string.

Comment: Sorry that was by mistake. I got by your function. thanks

Comment: I am also trying to use REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, 'name type:([^ ]*)', 0, 1, 'e') for my use case which is: 232mbkbkvc name type: ABC sdsjodhs997. Here I just want to get ABC from the string. I am not getting 'ABC' from the string though

Comment: @PriyankaLad . . . That case is rather hard to distinguish from a number following the space, but you can try:  `'ABC([^ ]+|( [-0-9]+)| )'`.